# Append to file through SSH is failing with Invalid Argument

Tags: linux, ssh

I'm trying to append to one of my inittab files through SSH from a different server. I've tried several attempts but seem to be failing. Any suggestions on how I can accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.

What I have that doesn't work:

```
ssh root@10.100.10.52 printf "foo\n" >> /etc/inittab
```

This yields the error of:

```
ssh: connect to host 0.100.10.52 port 22: Invalid argument
```

Comment: Your error message suggests you're not typing the IP address correctly . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote the command so it all executes remotely.  Right now, the redirect is taking the output from the SSH command and writing to the local /etc/inittab.

```
ssh root@10.100.10.52 'printf "foo\n" >> /etc/inittab'
```

Comment: sorry, pebkac... I copied the code from a script and had an extra character in the string ($ to be specific), anyway, I removed it and the double quoting works. thx.